# Sending cookies with python request

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to  make a post request with python's requests module.
I'm passing the `headers`, `cookies`, and `data` as part of the post request.
When I make the request,I get `400` `bad request` in the output. 
I verified the payload and it looks correct to me. I'm wondering If my syntax for cookie is correct.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import requests

session = "ASDFGHTR/=FGHYTYKSDMN="
lastmanaged = "9ycG9yYXRpb25fRGlyZWN0I"  

header = {'akm-accept':'akm/cookie'}

cookie = {'SESSION': session,
         'LASTMANAGED':lastmanaged}

data = {'client': '0ad3cfb66-4fa0-b94a-1bf712eae628&grant_type=password_assertion'}

url = "https://hostname-goes-here" 

session = requests.Session()
response = session.post(url, headers=header, cookies=cookie, data=data, 
            verify=False, allow_redirects=False)


print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
```

output:

```
{"code":"invalid_request","title":"One or more fields in request are invalid","incidentId":"f1fbba64-17e4-4d88-852f-01c137fa012e","requestId":"-5011561246754340090","solution":"none"}
400
```

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct: `data = {'client': '0ad3cfb66-4fa0-b94a-1bf712eae628&grant_type=password_assertion'}`? Don't you need _two_ fields here?

Comment: @ForceBru it is correct. I verified  the HTTP post data and I just have one field there.